# Recommended friends one degree separation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure

```
(Xref) IDUser1 and IDUser2 and table IDUser, UserName.
```

Xref table of friends is bidirectional (1, 2) and (2, 1).

What is the best way to get friends of my friends (that is not my friend) who has at least one of my friend as the mutual friend?

Comment: You should include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT friendL2.*
FROM [User] me

LEFT JOIN Xref relation1
ON relation1.IDUser1 = me.IDUser

LEFT JOIN Xref relation2
ON relation2.IDUser2 = me.IDUser

INNER JOIN [User] friendL1
ON relation1.IDUser2 = friendL1.IDUser
OR relation2.IDUser1 = friendL1.IDUser

LEFT JOIN Xref relation3
ON relation3.IDUser1 = friendL1.IDUser

LEFT JOIN Xref relation4
ON relation4.IDUser2 = friendL1.IDUser

INNER JOIN [User] friendL2
ON relation3.IDUser2 = friendL2.IDUser
OR relation4.IDUser1 = friendL2.IDUser

WHERE friendL2.IDUser != friendL1.IDUser -- This will tell that this guy can't be your friend
AND me.IDUser = @me
```

Just replace `@me` with your current id

You can also modify the last line by the next one if you wish to filter by UserName

```
AND me.Username = @me
```

Comment: I tried to do my best with the given description of the tables, not sure I understood very well what was the context

Comment: Thank you very much, please look at my answer, I hope that this time is slightly clearer question.

Answer (score -1):

```
IDUser1    |    IDUser2
1          |    2
2          |    1
           |
```

Sory for incomplete question, this is my table Xref, and I have another table User (IDUser, UserName). User with IDUser 1 is friend of IDUser 2 and vice versa.

I have this query for friends of friends

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.IDUser1,p.Username FROM Xref AS u 
inner join User as p on p.IDuser1=u.IDUser1
INNER JOIN (SELECT g.IDUser2 FROM Xref AS g WHERE g.IDUser1 = @IDUsern1
) AS f ON 
(u.IDUser2=f.IDUser2 AND u.IDUser1 <> @IDUser2)
WHERE U.IDUser1 NOT IN (Select Xref.IDUser2 from xref 
inner join Users on Users.IDUser1=Xref.IDuser1
where xref.IDUser2=@IDUser)
```

this works great, but I need users who are not my friends but have at least one of my friend as mutual friend

Comment: Please edit your question with those informations and remove this answer